# Spring Async execution with singleton/prototype scope

Tags: java, spring

We have large application implemented with multiple spring bean call. We haven't define any scope for bean (by default singleton).

Flow is like -

> `Master bean -> Child bean1 -> Child bean 2 -> Child bean 3 -> child bean 4 -> etc`

As of today, functionality is working fine. Child 2 call child 3 in loop and get result. This is sequential call.

Now, We have requirement to invoke child bean 3 parallel. I have done Asyn execution of bean 3 via Spring Async.

Now, Issue is -
Bean 3 is returning same result for all calls (for loop) invoked from bean 2. I tried with couple of changes - by updating scope to prototype for bean 2, bean 3, by method injection, etc.  But, Issue still persist.

I am stuck due to this. Any thought how i can fix this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We can only help you once you share piece of code

Comment: what does child3 bean do? post some code please

Comment: Singleton code is reentrant it must be Thread safe. Perhaps you have problems in Bean 3 with instance variables used to produce result. There must not be instance variables used. BTW it is just a first though and of course right question is from Angelo "what does child3 bean do?"

Comment: Code is too huge. I won't be able to post here.
Flow is something like,

Web service receive request (from multiple clients) -> Call Master Bean which has some validation -> Call child bean 1 which redirect another child bean 2a or 2b based on client -> Child bean 2 has foor loop iteration and call bean 3 -> Bean 3 process input data + get some data from Database and call bean 4 and get result -> Bean 4 has huge business logic which internally calls multiple beans, etc

Comment: Child bean 2 has for loop and sequential call to bean 3. No scope is defined in any bean (Singleton by default). Due to sequential execution, there is performance problem.

I am trying to make child bean 3 call to Async. So, For loop in bean 2 will make asyn call to bean 3 and wait for all threads to finish execution.